# SQLiteDB ListView with Delete

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I have researched this issue and I'm stuck on a few things still. First, I have yet to fully grasp how to take a 3 field database and show it in a ListView (I had previously just shown it in a scrollable text view). As it stands, I have 2 edit text which are the two field data being added along with the add button. What I want to do is show the DB in a ListView and have that ListView contain an X on each row on the right to delete that row. Initially I have users look at the table, match the right rid, enter that and hit a delete button.

My DataHelper.java

```
public class DataHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AdultSwim.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Requests";
private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
private static final String field1 = "Show";
private static final String field2 = "Want";
private Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private SQLiteStatement insertStmt;
private static final String INSERT = "insert into " + TABLE_NAME + "(Show) values (?)" + "(Want) values (?)";

public DataHelper(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);
        this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        this.insertStmt = this.db.compileStatement(INSERT);
    }

    public long insert(String name) {
        this.insertStmt.bindString(1, name);
        return this.insertStmt.executeInsert();
    }

    public void deleteOne(Long rowId) {
        String rownum = rowId.toString();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + "=" + rowId, null);
    }

    public  void deleteAll() {
        this.db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
    }

    public List<String> selectTableData() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                list.add(cursor.getString(0) + " " + cursor.getString(1));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
         return list;
    }

    private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        OpenHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Show VARCHAR NOT NULL, Want VARCHAR NOT NULL)");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think this is entirely accurate. I had one with only the primary key and one field, I don't think my 2nd field is being added.

And now the main Java

```
public class Item2 extends Activity {

    private DataHelper dh;
    private ImageView addButton;
    private ImageView displayNames;
    private ImageView delButton;
    private EditText show;
    private EditText want;
    private Editable varTextShow;
    private Editable varTextWant;
    private TextView outputTable;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.item2xml);
        dh = new DataHelper(this);
        addButton = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        displayNames = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.btnDisp);
        delButton = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.btnDel);
        show = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.showTitle);
        want = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.wantDegree);
        outputTable = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.output);

    addButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        varTextShow = show.getEditableText();
        String nameEntered = varTextShow.toString();
        dh.insert(nameEntered);
        show.setText("");
    }
});

displayNames.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        List<String> names = dh.selectTableData();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Shows Requested:\n");
        for (String name : names) {
            sb.append(name);
            sb.append("\n");
        }

            outputTable.setText(sb.toString());
    }

});

delButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        varTextShow = show.getEditableText();
        String rowToDelete;
        rowToDelete = varTextShow.toString();
        try{
            Long deleteRow = Long.parseLong(rowToDelete.trim());
            dh.deleteOne(deleteRow);
            show.setText("");
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext() ,"You must enter a number.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            show.setFocusable(true);
        }
    }

});
}
}
```

I'm sorry if this has been asked before. I have looked at the answers, seen examples and I just can't wrap my head around it. As it stands, the database is just showing up on the same scrollable window where the user enters the data.

Oh, and the main Java doesn't have the second field (field2) incorporated exactly yet.

I'm a total beginner at Android programming.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily an answer to all your problems but it can help you troubleshoot.

You can look at your database to find out what's been added by launching `adb` in terminal when the AVD is connected.

1. Open terminal and type `adb shell`
2. cd into the folder with the database (usually data/data/com.yourpackage/databases/)
3. Type `sqlite3 <database_file_name>`
4. If you did everything correctly until now, typing `.tables` should show you all your tables.
5. Enter `select * from <table_name>;` to see all your data.

This is kinda crucial in order to to DB development, that you can *see* your database and how the data gets entered.

Comment: Oh, I know about that. I've used adb shell with my last database. I guess I should at least first check to see if all fields are getting added to the database.
But looking at the main Java, you can see that I have yet to use
private EditText want; OR private Editable varTextWant;
Which is the newest field

EDIT: I ran my app. Everything works, but the moment I click on the menu item to go to add items to the database, it force closes.

Comment: Yeah I didnt get into the other problems, because you should check that the data is what is expected first, then you can narrow down your problem and ask again.

Answer (score 0):

write your delete query in list view adapter class in deleteIco.setOnClickListener()